# How can I disable log4j RollingFileAppender buffering for a demo?

Tags: java, log4j

I have a Java programming lab-exercise in a course with students that I'd like to artificially write to disk in an **inefficient** manner.  What I thought would be a mildly hard-to-find (as an exercise) would be having the app's log4j statements writing to disk in an **unbuffered** fashion.  The app intentionally has prolific log statements.

What's the best approach for configuring log4j to use a non-buffered file appender?  I'm using RollingFileAppender for now, but I don't care which file appender I ultimately use as long as it writes **inefficiently** to disk.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`FileAppender`](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/FileAppender.html) (and `RollingFileAppender` since it extends it) has a boolean `BufferedIO` property as well as `BufferSize` property (which you can set to 1 or some other low value).

Pick one and enjoy.

Comment: What is better in performance? 64 bytes buffer or no buffering? My typical message exceeds 64 bytes. Always exceeds 51.